# How to split a String on #*#*

Tags: java, android, split

I have a `String` with the following value:

```
B/W 0-2 hours of bus start time#*#*B/W 2-9 hours of bus start time#*#*Above 9 hours of bus start time--0%#*#*50%#*#*90%
```

How do you `split()` this on `#*#*`? I need the output as follows:

```
B/W 0-2 hours of bus start time

B/W 2-9 hours of bus start time

Above 9 hours of bus start time

0%

50%

90%
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: first determine a set of possible delimeters. `#*#*` is not a valid delimiter in your case, there is no single appearance of it in your text.

Comment: @J_D in java iam trying

Comment: @NMK I have posted updated answer, with your required output. check it.

Comment: @NMK Why did you remove the text of the question? Did any of the provided answers work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Split your string like this:

```
  String mStr = "B/W 0-2 hours of bus start time#*#B/W 2-9 hours of bus start time##Above 9 hours of bus start time--0%##50%##*90%";
        Log.e("mStr==", "===" + mStr);

        String[] pickList = mStr.split("#\\*#|##|--|##\\*|\\*");

        Log.e("pickList==", "===" + pickList.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < pickList.length; i++) {
            Log.e("pickList==", "===" + pickList[i]);
        }
```

Inside **pickList** you will get your output list with splitted data.

Comment: this won't work, as there is only 1 appearance of `#*#`, which will split it in 2 parts only

Comment: This does not produce the expected results.

Comment: @J_D wait, i am updating my answer.

Comment: @NMK check my updated answer. Its now showing as expected output you want

Comment: @NMK if you find my answer helpful, then you can accept tis answer, so other devs can also get help from this.

Comment: Sorry for not defining my issue properly, actually my required output should be like this:

B/W 0-2 hours of bus start time 0%
B/W 2-9 hours of bus start time 50%
Above 9 hours of bus start time 90%

some times iam getting extra strings too, i want to handle them to and i should display the out put in text view

Comment: @NMK, its okay. but my answer is perfect with your asked question. So its useful to others. :) Dont you think so? :)

Comment: definitely @Bhoomika

Answer (score 0):

Try the following -

```
yourString.split = yourString.split.replace("*","");
yourString.split = yourString.split.replace("--","");
String[] pickList = yourString.split("##");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string should contain the same delimiters. If you have different delimiters, you need to predict which delimiters can be there and pass those delimiters as arguments to the split() separated by | sign.

Such as, to use # and * sign as delimiters, you need to write like this :
stringvariable.split("\#|\*");

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) matching either 1+ repetitions of `#*` or match `--`

```
(?:#\*)+|--
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ev4GpF/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/awIwY0)

For example:

```
String s = "B/W 0-2 hours of bus start time#*#*B/W 2-9 hours of bus start time#*#*Above 9 hours of bus start time--0%#*#*50%#*#*90%";
String[] parts = s.split("(?:#\\*)+|--");

for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

Result

```
B/W 0-2 hours of bus start time
B/W 2-9 hours of bus start time
Above 9 hours of bus start time
0%
50%
90%
```

Answer (score 0):

String finalValue = "";
String mystring="B/W 0-2 hours of bus start time#*#*B/W 2-9 hours of bus start time#*#*Above 9 hours of bus start time--0%#*#*50%#*#*90%";

```
String[] splitSt1 = mystring.split("--");
String detailsString = splitSt1[0];
String percentageString = splitSt1[1];
String[] detailsSt1 = detailsString.split("#\\*#\\*");
String[] percentageSt2 = percentageString.split("#\\*#\\*");

if(detailsSt1.length == detailsSt1.length ){
    for(int i=0;i<=(detailsSt1.length-1);i++ )
    {
        finalValue = finalValue +"* "+ detailsSt1[i]+ "-->" + percentageSt2 [i] +"\n"+"\n";
        my_text_view_id.setText(finalValue);
    }
```

}

out put:

- B/W 0-2 hours of bus start time --> 0%
- B/W 2-9 hours of bus start time --> 50%
- Above 9 hours of bus start time --> 90%